# I need to create a list of numbers in text file

Tags: c#

hello please i have an program to create numbers in text file based on textboxes value there is three textboxes the first for typing an not changed number the textbox2 for typing the first number and the textbox3 for typing the last number 
but in the output for my program give me like this

015 100
015 101
015 102
015 103
015 104
015 105
015 106
015 107
015 108

but int the text box I'm typed the first :0000100
the last 0000108 and 015 is the fixed number 
and me i need in the text file be like this

015 0000100
015 0000101
015 0000102
015 0000103
015 0000104
015 0000105
015 0000106
015 0000107
015 0000108

and this is the code of the button

```
int a, b;   
a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

System.IO.StreamWriter objwriter;
String fm = @"C:\Users\HP PAVILION\Desktop\text.txt";
objwriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fm);

int i;
for (i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text); i++)
{
    objwriter.Write(textBox1.Text + " " + i + "\r\n");
    progressBar1.Value = (100 / (b - a)) * i;
}
objwriter.Close();
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: Write the value using as a String.  ToString("000000000");

Comment: 0000100 = `100` as an int... `0000100` would be good to store in a string however

Comment: or + i.ToString().PadLeft(7,'0')

Answer (score 3):

`i.ToString("D7")` means:

> Please convert my number to Leading Zero in length of 7 characters.

**From [The Decimal ("D") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString)**

> The precision specifier indicates the minimum number of digits desired
>   in the resulting string. If required, the number is padded with zeros
>   to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision
>   specifier. If no precision specifier is specified, the default is the
>   minimum value required to represent the integer without leading zeros.

```
objwriter.Write(textBox1.Text + i.ToString("D7") + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: thank you and please i have an other probleme the progress bar to work in big numbers

Comment: @AbdelkaderBachr, Another problem another post, SO Rules, Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your number to have leading zeros:

```
objwriter.Write(textBox1.Text + " " + i.ToString("0000000") + "\r\n");
```

Comment: thank you and please i have an other probleme the progress bar to work in big numbers do you have some solutions

Comment: what is your definition of  'big numbers' ?